# How to separate html header and content with css and make the content scrollable

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm quite unexperienced with html and css, but I need to make a simple html-page for my courses. I am facing the problem, that the content on my page isn't scrolling correctly. If you look at this page: http://clubnights.square7.ch/impr.html you will see what I am talking about. It should be stupid newbie mistake so I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change height to `max-height:75%` instead of `height:100%`.

```
#content {
    max-height: 75%;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Yeah, well it is a possible solution but not the best one. The content-part doesn't fill the whole rest of the space and depending on the resolution and window size of the browser the problem may appear again.

Comment: @user1851290: Then you change height to `max-height:75%`, nothing else. see my edited answer.

Comment: Hmmm.. nope, the scrollbar still disappear if i resize the browser window. http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/1549/kbscr.png

Comment: well, look: here http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/8915/kbscr2.png is the scrollbar not completely visible. Thats why the content isn't visible too. I just want that the scrollbar is completely visible if the content doesn't fit into a window to make sure that the content is visible as well like on this screenshot: http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/6519/kbscr3.png